# How to make multiple div columns to adjust to content size and and fit parent?

Tags: html, css, gridview

I need to customize a `data grid`, which is made of `divs` as `rows` and `cells`, not `table` components.

I need each column in this grid adjusts its size according its content. At same time I need to make all columns fit parent component so that there's no space before or after the columns.

I just can use `CSS` to achieve this. No `Javascript`.

How to make multiple `div` columns to adjust to content size and and fit parent using `CSS`?

Comment: you can do that using CSS Flex property https://jsfiddle.net/ffxsam/x96tx1y5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using flexbox with only a parent div as flex-container and child divs that are shown like table cells :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.flex-container {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
 width:30%;
 margin:1%;
 padding:5px;
}

.flex-item-01 {
 background-color: #A65E5C;
}

.flex-item-02 {
 background-color: #9BCAA0;
}

.flex-item-03 {
 background-color: #37ABA7;
}

.flex-item-04 {
 background-color: #1A9FEC;
}

.flex-item-05 {
 background-color: #EA0FBC;
}

.flex-item-06 {
 background-color: #6A9F00;
}

.flex-item strong {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
   
   <div class="flex-item flex-item-01">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>01</strong> 
   </div>
    
   <div class="flex-item flex-item-02">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>02</strong>
   </div>
    
   <div class="flex-item flex-item-03">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>03</strong>
   </div>

   <div class="flex-item flex-item-04">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>04</strong> 
   </div>
    
   <div class="flex-item flex-item-05">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>05</strong>
   </div>
    
   <div class="flex-item flex-item-06">
    <em>Flex Item</em>
    <strong>06</strong>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do that with display:inline-block and vertical-align:top to childrens

```css
.parent {

}
.parent div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right:-4px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a taller div.</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
</div>
```